# php array for each in for each

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get a select list with values from `$staff`
The bit i am struggling is selecting the staff that are already enrolled from `$entry->enrolments`.

If the `$staff id` exists in `$entry->enrolments` select it in the select list

`$entry` = Record from mysql

`$staff` = list of staff in an array.

`$entry->enrolments` = comma seperated values of enrolled staff

```
<select name="tutor[]" id="tutor" multiple="multiple" size="5" class="required" title="Select Staff">

<?php
    $entry = get_record("staff_development", "id", $id);
    $staff = get_records("user", "deleted", "0", "lastname ASC", "id,firstname,lastname,idnumber");
    $sdenrolments=array($entry->enrolments);
    $people = explode(",", $entry->enrolments);


    foreach($staff as $tutor){
    foreach($people as $person){

    if($tutor->id>1)echo '<option value="'.$tutor->id.'"';
    if ($person==$tutor->id) {echo 'selected="selected"';}
    echo '>'.$tutor->lastname.' '.$tutor->firstname.'</option>';
    }
    }
?>

</select>
```

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: try producing more output after 1st foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is the easiest way to tell if a value is in an array :) Replace your loops with this:

```
foreach($staff as $tutor){
    echo '<option value="'.$tutor->id.'"';
    if(in_array($tutor->id, $people))
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    echo '>'.$tutor->lastname.' '.$tutor->firstname.'</option>';
}
```

You might also want to rename your variable from `people` to `enrolled_staff` or something a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` block is confusing.  You are checking for `$tutor->id > 1` when opening the option tag, but aren't when closing it.  [PaulP.R.O mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10801384/138383) `in_array` which you should replace your foreach loops with.  Here is your `if` block cleaned up and set the check for selection inline.

```
if($tutor->id > 1) {
    echo '<option value="'.$tutor->id.'" ' . (($person==$tutor->id) ? ' selected="selected"': '') . '>';
    echo $tutor->lastname.' '.$tutor->firstname;
    echo '</option>';
}
```